# Gnuplot : skip missing data points and xticlabels

Tags: plot, gnuplot, point

I would like to skip some points to draw a graph in gnuplot and not connecting lines through missing points.

It is the same problem than : https://superuser.com/questions/440947/in-gnuplot-how-to-plot-with-lines-but-skip-missing-data-points

The gnuplot help says :

> set datafile missing "?"
>
> set style data lines
>
> plot '-'
>
> ```
>  1 10
>  2 20
>  3 ?
>  4 40
>  5 50
>  e
> ```
>
> plot '-' using 1:2
>
> ```
>  1 10
>  2 20
>  3 ?
>  4 40
>  5 50
>  e
> ```
>
> plot '-' using 1:($2)
>
> ```
>  1 10
>  2 20
>  3 ?
>  4 40
>  5 50
>  e
> ```
>
> The first plot will recognize only the first datum in the "3 ?" line. It
>   will use the single-datum-on-a-line convention that the line number is "x"
>   and the datum is "y", so the point will be plotted (in this case erroneously)
>   at (2,3).
>
> The second plot will correctly ignore the middle line. The plotted line
>   will connect the points at (2,20) and (4,40).
>
> The third plot will also correctly ignore the middle line, but the plotted
>   line will not connect the points at (2,20) and (4,40).

---

In order not to connect the points (2,20) and (4,40), we have to put a $ symbol :   plot '-' using 1:($2)

I'd like to do the same thing with the following line :

```
plot using i:xticlabels(1) title columnheader(i)
```

But it doesn't work (i tried ($i):xticlabels(1) and other things... it doesn't work)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `column(i)` to select the i-th column. `$1` is a shortcut for `column(1)` but you cannot use `$i` as shortcut for `column(i)`:

```
set style data lines
i=2
plot '-' using (column(i)):xticlabels(1) title columnheader(i)
A B
1 10
2 20
3 ?
4 40
5 50
e
```

[image]